# how to calculate with the input of edittext to a textview

Tags: java, android

I have a question and i really don't know how I need to do it. 
I wanna make an app. It will be an app where you type in how many stairs you have walked via an editText and then the amount of calories you burned doing that in a TextView. Do you guys know how to do this?

Comment: So is this your homework...?

Comment: @JeroenBoot the point is, at least, search for it first. The internet is your best friend. By using `Android Studio` as your IDE, you can just easily drag and drop things. And from there, if you're stuck at something, always try to search for the answers first.

Comment: No, im making it for the other students in my school. Just for fun! @vilpe89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use afterTextChangedListener() on your EditText and use the formula to calculate calories burnt based on the text of EditText at that point.

After this you can use setText on your TextView to the updated burn.